# Why does my generated mesh have some distortion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, procedural-generation

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvqXI.gif)
this mesh is generated by my script.I want to generate a voronoi diagram and split a plane to three zones.And I drag a material to one of the zones to test the generated result.

```
using SharpVoronoiLib;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fortune : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<VoronoiEdge> edges;
    private void Awake()
    {
        List<VoronoiSite> sites = new List<VoronoiSite>
        {
        new VoronoiSite(22, 26),
        new VoronoiSite(10, 40),
        new VoronoiSite(38, 5)
        };
        edges = VoronoiPlane.TessellateOnce(
            sites,
            0, 0,
            50, 50
        );
        //site represent a zone. ClockwisePoints represent some points,which makes up the zone.
        for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count; i++)
        {
            var ver = new List<Vector3>();
            var uv= new List<Vector2>();
            foreach (var item in sites[i].ClockwisePoints)
            {
                float x = (float)item.X;
                float y = (float)item.Y;
                ver.Add(new Vector3(x, 0, y));
                uv.Add(new Vector2(x/50, y/50));
            }
            ver.Reverse();
            uv.Reverse();
            List<int> tri = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 1; j < ver.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                tri.Add(0);
                tri.Add(j);
                tri.Add(j + 1);
            }
            
            Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
            mesh.vertices = ver.ToArray();
            mesh.triangles = tri.ToArray();
            mesh.uv=uv.ToArray();
            var gameObject = Resources.Load<GameObject>("test");
            MeshFilter meshfilter = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            meshfilter.mesh = mesh;
            Instantiate(gameObject,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        } 
    }
```

Maybe the uv setting has error.But I don't know the reason.Thank for your reply.

After some try,I find if I delete height map in shader.The error has disappeared.I don't know reason.
[shader windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnjEF.png)

Comment: could you try with a more simple texture, like a checkerboard with the letter 'b' on each square for instance ? it would help to understand the distortion.